# Index of cumulative distribution function

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, distributions

When trying to compute this

```
f[x1_, x2_] := -Log[CDF[MultinormalDistribution[{0, 0}, 
{{1, rho}, {rho,1}}],{(mu1 - Log[x1])/sigma1, (mu2 -  Log[x2])/sigma2}]]
D[f[x1, x2], x1]
```

the result contained an expression containing the function "CDF" with an upper index, i.e. "CDF^{(0,(1,0)}.
Unfortunately, I have no idea what this expression means. Can anybody help me or tell me where to find information about expressions like this one? I could not find anything in the Documentation.

Best regards, 
Moe

Comment: `D[foo[a, {b, c}], b]` (outputs as $\text{foo}^{(0,\{1,0\})}$[$a,\{b,c\}$])   is the first partial derivative with respect to `b` of  `foo`.

Comment: *Mathematica* 12 gives you the result in the form you likely desire:  `(E^(-((mu1 - Log[x1])^2/(2 sigma1^2)))
    Erfc[((rho (mu1 - Log[x1]))/sigma1 - (mu2 - Log[x2])/sigma2)/(
    Sqrt[2] Sqrt[1 - rho^2])])/(2 Sqrt[2 \[Pi]]
    sigma1 x1 CDF[
    MultinormalDistribution[{0, 0}, {{1, rho}, {rho, 1}}], {(
     mu1 - Log[x1])/sigma1, (mu2 - Log[x2])/sigma2}])`.